# How long does it take for the stress stains to vanish?

Tags: the-hunter-call-of-the-wild

After you kill an animal, there is a "blood stain" that appear at the map and if I'm not mistaken, they are called stress stains. It means animals will likely avoid those places.

So, how long does it take for those stains to vanish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/theHunter/comments/fv5vtt/how_long_does_it_take_for_those_stains_to_vanish/): "*That purple bloch is called hunting pressure and it goes away as you kill animals and create hunting pressure in other areas in the map.*"